# How do I get the search results (tableview) appear automatically in a SearchDisplayViewController when search bar is clicked?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a `SearchDisplayViewController` that has the search result `tableview` that appears after you click the `searchbar` and type some characters. I am wondering if it is possible to have the searchresult `tableview` before you type any characters? I will post some related code below.

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return 1;
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: what do you want to display if searchbar is empty ?

Comment: If the search bar is empty, I would like one cell to say location. Since I can use it to show a certain location

Comment: Fill the searchResultArray with objects you wan to show! If you want to show no location cell.. its basically return (searchResultArray.count=0)?1:searchResultArray.count; in -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section; method

Comment: just check if your array for `tableView` is empty then fill it with the location data that you want. @ThisIs